# how do you view the overloads visual studio mac 2019

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-2019, overload-resolution

Does anyone know how to view the multiple overloads in visual studio 2019 mac intellisense? Google search comes up blank for this topic.

I'm just trying to find out how to scroll through the overloads on intellisense popup (there are no up/down arrows, even if multiple overloads are present), see screenshot, see it shows +3 overloads, but there's no way to see what they are:

[image]

Can't find anything written on this. Thanks.

Comment: Can ctrl+shift+space work for this situation?  In VS for windows you can put the cursor in `( )`, `ctrl+shift+space` and it will display the overloads list, then  you can easily select it by simply pressing `up or down`. But not sure if it's the same in VS for MAC.

Comment: I tried ctrl + shift + space in VS Mac...did nothing whatsoever. Hence the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, ctrl + shift + space does work on VS Mac, if the cursor is in between the (), you get up/down arrows. If you just mouse-over with intellisense, you see that it has overloads, but you cannot see what they are. At least I can see how you find them now.

Comment: Hi friend, glad to know this issue is resolved, please mark it as self answer so that others with similar situation can easily find the useful info. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), just a reminder 
 :-)